# Rotate Images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

How can I rotate a set of images in an ellipse? how to get each point on a ellipse at some center(x,y)point.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) has numerous 3d Carousel plugins: http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/3d+carousel+type:project_project

The first result, [Carousel3d](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/carousel3d), comes with full-operable examples that you can cut/paste from if you're not confident enough to tamper with Javascript directly.